# Exploring Probabilities With Cards

Tags: probability

As a recreational follower of mathematics, I am comfortable with questions like *"without replacement, what are the chances that from a deck of 52 well shuffled cards you draw two aces?"* (1/221 I hope!)

However, I struggle with questions like *"what are the chances that there are exactly two aces adjacent to each other within a deck of 52 well shuffled cards?"*

I attempt to reason that the aces could appear at positions 1,2 / 2,3 / 3,4 ... 50,51 / 51,52 i.e. 51 chances.  But I'm not sure how to calculate my target outcomes let alone determine what are all the possible outcomes.

Similarly, the probability of a run of five cards (a run of numbers e.g. 1-5 or 2-6 or 3-7 ... 9-K.

I'd like to research this more and also expectation e.g. how many pairs would you expect to find in a deck of 52 well shuffled cards.  Expectation particularly troubles me - for example, how on earth does one calculate whether a run of, say, 7 red cards is normal or abnormal or four lots of pairs?

If anyone has come across a good site that goes over these things, please point me in the right direction and feel free to suggest what search terms I should put in Google.  My endeavours so far haven't borne much fruit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question about the aces requires some care since you have to subtract the probability that there is more than one pair of adjacent aces, which can be done using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.